# Behaviour of divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I have some divs which don't behave like I wish.

```
<div class="list-product-with-border">
    <div style="width:80px; display:inline-block;">img</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;"><b>Productname</b></div>
    <div style="float:right; width:80px;">
        <div>
            <button id="editBtn">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="removeBtn">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvwz0n8/)

Two problems here:

1. the bordered divs is not high enough: the 'remove' button is not visually in the bordered div
2. When the 'product name' is [longer](http://jsfiddle.net/ps8s3h3s/), the buttons are rendered under the div with the product name. I would like the product name to be over multiple lines when this happens. The three divs should always be next to eachother.

The first and last div has a fixed width, the middle div (product name) should stretch with the size of the bordered div

Comment: for 2 you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` you need to give the div a width but this will make a break when the length of the div is reached, [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ognfy7kq/)

Comment: @Déjàvu 'the middle div (product name) should stretch'

Comment: Yeah, sorry i just read the last part of your question. Nevermind my solution then :)

Comment: There is the answer for your question - http://jsfiddle.net/qrvwz0n8/9/ I have just added a float property to all divs which will stick to each other in the main div.

Comment: @Murtaza: this solves my first problem. Thanks! Second one is not solved yet though: http://jsfiddle.net/qrvwz0n8/10/

Comment: See my edited answer.. Its what you asked

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use a table for this. Each row of the table is an item, and you have a column of images, a column of names, and a column of actions. Is this any different to the tables used for invoices?

I can't quite get the effect you want, but improvements can be made: a floated element should come *before* the elements that are to go around it - so in this case, it should be the first thing inside the list-product-with-border container. Also, you should either have an element with `clear:both` at the end of the container, or set the container to have `overflow:hidden` to force the floated element to be inside.

Comment: Using multiple tables, it works... Thanks for the other tips by the way. http://jsfiddle.net/ps8s3h3s/1/

Comment: @Fortega That works, but it's not really... ideal. You should try to have a single table with each row being an item. It may be tricky to get the borders right, but it will make more sense semantically.

Comment: I know, but that would be a lot of added html and css for the same result: adding borders (top, bottom, sometimes left, sometimes right) td, bottom margin to the trs and divs with margin inside the tds (because tds with padding will make an 'interrupted' border. So I will probably leave it like it is now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this?

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvwz0n8/8/)

```
<style>
.list-product-with-border {
    padding:3px;
    width:60%;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
```

And now the HTML

```
    <div class="list-product-with-border">
    <div style="width:80px; display:inline-block;">img</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; height: auto;"><b>Productname Is the right choice baby, as you can see its just done</b></div>
    <div style="float:right; width:180px;margin-top: 10px;">
        <div style="float: left;">
            <button id="editBtn">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <button id="removeBtn">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the divs should be next to eachother, also with a large product name. So this solution is not right for me, sorry.

Comment: Still the same problem, @Saswat. Maybe your screen is much bigger than mine... http://jsfiddle.net/qrvwz0n8/11/ -> the product name div is displayed under the img div instead of next to it

Answer (score 0):

> You must use display:table-cell instead of display:table-column and remove float:left for .divCell.
>
> And add this style:

```
.headRow{
    display:table-row;
}
```